# python SSDP discovery error

Tags: windows, sockets, python-2.7, ssdp

```
req = ['M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1',
           'HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900',
           'MAN: "ssdp:discover"',
           'ST: ssdp:all',
           'MX: 3',
           "", ""]
req = '\r\n'.join(req)
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
[sock.sendto(req, ('239.255.255.250',1900)) for i in range(3)]
resp, (addr,port) = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

the SSDP discovery request i perform with this code retrieves me only the rootdevice instead of all the LAN connected devices (samsung tv, sky+hd box, laptop, PCs).
does anyone know how to display all the devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only wait for one answer so it seems logical that you only get one :)
This should show all of them (including the duplicates that the devices/services send).

```
while (True):
    resp, (addr,port) = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print resp
```